# How would I create a circuit that gives an output similar to the one of a button when a block behind is powered with a lever but not when not powered?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

Sorry about the length of the title of this question. I have a circuit where I am trying to get an output like the one of a button from an observer looking at a piece of redstone dust that is powered by a lever. This is obviously simple enough, but the catch is that I only want the observer to give an output when the redstone dust it is observing is powered on, not when it turns off. I have tried so many different ways. The time it takes the redstone dust that the observer is observing varies every time by the way. A quick reply would really be appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: Do you just want the pulse from the observer? And do you need to use the observer or would a method to create the pulse a different way work too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

use this redstone contraption.
Also, I couldn't fully understand "The time it takes the redstone dust that the observer is observing varies every time by the way" so if you find a way to do that just connect it to this.

---

this is how to make it and what this does:

1. do that "The time it takes the redstone dust that the observer is observing varies every time" thing
2. if you know how to make an AND gate skip to # 9
3. place 2 parallel repeaters with 1 block between them
4. place 2 comparator facing towards each other, one on the end of each repeater
5. right click both comparators
6. place 1 redstone block for each comparator (the combination of *signal + right clicked comparator + redstone block* is 1 way to make a not gate)
7. place a comparator on the block that the 2 comparators are facing and right click it
8. place a redstone block for the comparator (this NOT gate can take 2 inputs and be a NAND (NOT AND) gate, also note how the repeaters do not take input from the redstone block)
9. now put the observer to the input of one repeater
10. put the redstone dust itself for the other input (so the observer has to give signal and the redstone must be on, therefore not sending a signal when the button goes off)

Comment: Thanks so much! That is just perfect. Dont worry bout the time thing.